# jQuery delay error with Form Validator Plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a pop-up box using the ZURB.org script (working perfectly fine). Within this reveal box I have a Form which the user can fill out certain information. This validates perfectly using the plugin - presenting the nice looking error messages aligned fine.

My problem is, with this been a reveal box, when the user clicks out of the reveal box (to exit) the validation icons still appear there until the user manually clicks them.

I've managed to figure out if they click the 'Exit' icon at the top of the box, it will close them by means of this code:

```
<a class="close-reveal-modal" onclick="$('#jobForm').validationEngine('hideAll');">Exit</a>
```

How ever, I now want to use a bit of jQuery to automatically 'Hide' these error messages after, lets say, 3 seconds.

The code I have so far is:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#job_submit").click(function() {
$('#jobForm').validationEngine('hideAll').delay(3000);
 });
 });
</script>
```

job_submit is the ID and name of the Submit button within the form. I went one step further with Chromes debugging tool and wrote within the console the following code:

$('#jobForm').validationEngine('hideAll').delay(3000);

When the form validation errors were present. This came back with the error 'Type Error'.

From this point on I am unsure as to how to solve this Type Error.

As always, many thanks for your help.

**Update**

The Div Classes are not named the same, for some reason, the first part of the div is the name of the form field itsself e.g jdesformError parentFormjobForm formError

How ever, the last 2 sections appear to be consistent.

I tried this in the console - 
    $('.jdesformError parentFormjobForm formError').delay(1000).trigger('click');

and it passed with flying colours however, the 'error' field didn't vanish when it does when i physically click it, would it be something to do with the reveal box i'm using?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#job_submit").click(function() {
        // click all the errors at once
        $('.formError').delay(3000).trigger('click');
     });
});
```

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. I understand where you're coming from how ever, on checking the div classes for the 'errors' them selves, they appear to be attaching to each of the 'Form field names' - as such - jdesformError parentFormjobForm formError. With jdes been the form name. Is there a way to just click on all div classes with 'formError' included?

Comment: I don't know exactly what you mean. But. in the example code above, I'm using a generic class used by the validator plugin called "formError". This class is applied in EVERY error tooltip, independent of the form or input name. I think it should work. Anyway if I missing something here, please let me know. Glad to help.

Comment: I inputted your code into the console and it works! - $('.formError').delay(3000).trigger('click'); - but it doesn't work entirely as it's not activated once the button has been clicked? The button code is <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="job_submit" id="job_submit" /> so I can't see why not?

Comment: I added the entire code into the console, this runs how ever, seems to return the entire page on the console. With removing the ready(function) line, it then returns the 'submit' button, as if to simulate clicking it, how ever, it still doesn't hide the errors? Yet if I do put the single line as shown in the comment above, it does work?